# calling wp_current_user() in wordpress makes non jquery

Tags: jquery, session, wordpress, membership

I am creating website in WP with s2member plugin.I used these few lines inside where I used the s2member member code

```
 $current_user = get_current_user_id(); / get current looged in user ID
    $_SESSION['id']=$current_user;  // put that in session
```

I have queries that is this the right way to set session in WP? (I used set_session on top)
Results:

- The jquery doesn't run after if uncomment above code..
- The grey bar on top of WP that shows current logged in user becomes complete blank,it doesn't show any logged in user.

  [image: bar while commented code]

I thnk that there is different way to set session in WP or it doesn't allow you to do so..
Any help in this regard.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried Google? http://www.frank-verhoeven.com/using-session-in-wordpress/

Comment: @Jamie that tell you how to start session,It doesn't help you how  put somehting in session variable.. I follwed the same approach..

Comment: 1.- Your Q is not clear. What are you asking? (try to make just one Q by post) 2.- Put some code related to jquery issue. 3.- Probably `The grey bar on top of WP` info has nothing to do with your showed code.

Comment: @NomikOS yes the grey bar shows alot.. if I uncomment the code,it show me logged in username,if I comment it it show me complete grey bar without any username.

Comment: What if you use `'u_id'` instead of `'id'`?

Comment: @brasofilo ahhh cool idea may be id is already set.. let me do that meanwhile

Comment: @brasofilo the results are same.. I noticed one more thing that $current_user = get_current_user_id(); is the line that is causing the REMOVAL of USERNAME from grey bar..

Comment: Oh, as a matter of fact, `$current_user` is a WP global variable, use another var name.

Comment: @brasofilo it works kindly mail it as answer

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the context where this is being used, but two things:

- `'id'` is too much of a common argument, used everywhere, try `'u_id'`
  It comes to mind because of this WordPress Answer: [List of reserved names in $_POST and $_REQUEST used by WordPress 3.5](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77339/12615)
- `$current_user`  is a global WordPress core variable, use another name. And as suggested in the linked Answer, ***prefix everything***.